# How can fix pip connection to 127.0.0.1 on my mac?

Tags: pip, connection

Pip version: pip 18.0 
Python version: 2.7.15
Operating system: mac 10.13.4

```
sudo -H pip install virtualenvwrapper
Password:
Collecting virtualenvwrapper
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x101c0e710>, 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/virtualenvwrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x101c0e810>, 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/virtualenvwrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x101c0e910>, 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/virtualenvwrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x101c0ea10>, 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/virtualenvwrapper/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x101c0eb10>, 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/virtualenvwrapper/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvwrapper (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenvwrapper
```

Why I connection to 127.0.0.1 ?

So how can I fix this！ thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably connecting behind a proxy, which you need to parse the proxy creds. This error is basically when your pip is trying to connect to the net to download the package installer, but fails to establish the connection.

Try: `pip install -–proxy=user:pass@host:port <package>`

or `pip install --proxy="" <package>` to fool the proxy

Unless if the failure is on ssl verification, you can then parse a skip verify flag.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I connection to 127.0.0.1 ?

Because you've configured a proxy and forgot about it. Look for proxy settings in your environment variables with `set | fgrep -i proxy`.

Also check your `~/.pip/pip.conf`.